# Reference.cs is not auto generated after adding 3rd Party WSDL as a service Reference

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asp.net-mvc-5, wsdl

I am trying to add a reference to a 3rd Part Web Service that uses SOAP. I have a WSDL which is valid.

When I add a service reference the Reference.cs file is left empty except for the header comments.

I have tried using the default settings and I have also tried unchecking

> Reuse types in Referenced Assemblies

This gives me the following errors

> Failed to generate code for the service reference 'ServiceReference1'.  Please check other error and warning messages for details.

And the warnings

> Cannot import wsdl:portType
>   Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
>   Error: Schema with target namespace 'http://staging-creditbureau-api.stubbsgazette.ie/soap/' could not be found.
>   XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://staging-creditbureau-api.stubbsgazette.ie/soap/']/wsdl:portType[@name='apiSoap']

And

> Cannot import wsdl:binding
>   Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
>   XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://staging-creditbureau-api.stubbsgazette.ie/soap/']/wsdl:portType[@name='apiSoap']
>   XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://staging-creditbureau-api.stubbsgazette.ie/soap/']/wsdl:binding[@name='apiSoap']

I have followed the instructions by [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) Is there any more steps that I'm missing ?